# SQL: Counting the result of a select statement

Tags: sql, select, having-clause

I have maybe a dumb question?  Anyways, I can't figure it out.

```
blah blah
GROUP BY cp.c, cp.r
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(cp.r)
                  FROM cp
                  WHERE cp.r IN (SELECT cr.r
                                 FROM cr
                                  WHERE cr.r LIKE '%blah&'));
```

SELECT cr.r has multiple values and it works alright

The problem is in HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(cp.r)) 
Can I even do that?

So far the query returns nothing which should not happen according to the data.

Comment: This is valid as far as I know. Make a fiddle with some sample data demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I am trying to select the rows where count (COUNT(*)) (the total rows of the same group) equals the amount of (SELECT COUNT) of different rows that match a description.

Comment: I can see that, and I think it should work. Since you claim that it's not working, please post enough information so we can see the problem.

Comment: http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/1036  I posted the code I'm working with there. Sorry about the spacing.  Not sure how to fix that.  Goal (ignoring part of it that I haven't coded yet): Write a single query that shows the community names that are in a central region. Anyways, each CommunityAreaNumber has multiple entries with varying types of regions.  I hope my teacher doesn't mind me posting my solution online, but I'm really stuck.

Comment: Where is the input data? The best way to provide this is by making a sqlfiddle.

Comment: Also, please tag your question with the DBMS, since there may be differences between implementations (mysql, sql-server, Oracle, etc).

Comment: Huh? Do what?  The input data is thousands....but I do have an ERD http://www.thatlink.com/Classes/Main/DisplayImage.aspx?Section=cis2725fa13&File=ChicagoParksErd.png

Comment: Just make a small sample.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38303/discussion-between-user963070-and-barmar)